# Substitutions to a visual block leave highlights - Vim

Tags: vim

I just started using vim a few hours ago and am working on a project.  Having a decent amount of fun and frustration alike -- mostly fun though :).

I am running into an odd situation though which might be due to using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus), but any help would be much appreciated.

When I visually select several lines using `shift-v + j` then do a replace on those lines to comment them `:s/^/#`, it successfully does what I would expect and replace the start of the lines of the visual block with `#`.  However, at the same time it highlighted every `^` in my file (basically the first char of every line is now highlighted).

A similar thing happened when I did another substitution of `:s/^/<TAB>` to shift a block of code over for indention.  The added tabs on each of those lines are highlighted the same.

Neither of these highlights has gone away even after I go on editing.  Why is it doing that?  What can I do to get it to stop?  What are some easier ways to achieve what I was doing if there are any?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Janus (nor know what it is), but `:nohl` (for nohighlight) will get rid of all the highlighting, after a search & substitute.

Comment: @ldigas: care to return and add that as an answer? :)

Comment: @sarnold - Really didn't think that was "worth" the answer.

Comment: @ldigas: it might _feel_ simple once you know `:nohl`, but knowing what to look for in the first place might be daunting. (Especially with `vim`. :)

Comment: @sarnold - Okey, you got a point there.

Comment: That was indeed the case.  I tried several google searches but didn't know what to search for.  When I searched for `:nohl` however, there was a wealth of knowledge.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, your problem is due to Janus: **the `hlsearch` option is off by default.** Here, the guy who made Janus simply decided for you that you wanted/needed search highlight so he turned the option on. Because you are still very new to Vim, you should drop Janus right now and learn vanilla Vim. Your `~/.vimrc` will grow progressively - following **your** taste, needs and discoveries - and you will choose **yourself** what plugins to put into your `~/.vim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Janus (nor know what it is), but `:nohl` (for nohighlight) will get rid of all the highlighting, after a search & substitute.

Comment: And if you just don't want to see searches highlighted to begin with, put `set nohlsearch` in your .vimrc (.vimrc.local in Janus).